# I got "BE" appended text after year in date picker. I searched for it but I didn't get any success

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13, swift4.2

I am getting "BE" as postfix in year(in a date picker). This issue is not for all devices. Issue appears only in one of my client's device and he is using iOS 13.5.1(latest)
[image: iPhone image]

**My code for date picker**

```
//Formate Date
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!
//ToolBar
let toolbar = UIToolbar();
toolbar.sizeToFit()
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneDatePicker))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker))
toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
txtField.inputView = datePicker
```

Comment: How have you configured your DatePicker? what is the Locale of the phone set to?

Comment: What's your locale? `buddhist` seems to use `BE` for the era.

Comment: `let df = DateFormatter(); df.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .buddhist); df.dateStyle = .full; print(df.string(from: Date()))` reproduce it: `Monday, June 22, 2563 BE`.

Comment: I updated my code in question please look at code and give me your suggestions. Thank you in advance

Comment: See the previous comment, select another identifier for you calendar. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/identifier

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But this issue is not for all devices. Issue appears in only one of my client's device and he is using iOS 13.5.1(latest)

Comment: That wasn't clear from reading the question, you need to update your question and clarify this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. I have updated my question for more clarification.